# XAML Vertically align only top stackpanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a view that contains two stackpanels (main ones). The top one is a spinner and "One Moment Please..." that I need centered vertically. The bottom one appears when the top one disappears and I need it stretched so the content appears at the top of the window.

```
     <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <local:BusyIndicator VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="50" Height="50" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="One Moment Please" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding Path=HasError, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock
                    Visibility="{Binding Path=HasError, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                    Text="{Binding Path=ErrorMessage}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource inverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
</Stackpanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The issue that keeps happening is that the bottom stackpanel is vertically centered and the content does not move to the top of the window.

I apologize but I am not able to show the actual view (NDA). What I am trying to do (Right Image), what is happening (Left Image). NOTE: Only the text or the spinner show up at one time. I am not trying to align the two, just make the spinner center vertically when the text is not displayed.

[image]

Comment: Use a `Grid` or `DockPanel` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd like to see a screenshot of what you need and a screenshot of what you currently have

Comment: I'm still not sure what's being asked, you just want the text to display at the top, and the spinner to be centered? Not sure how to interpret "I am not trying to align the two, just make the spinner center vertically when the text is **not** displayed."

Comment: Only the spinner or the text are displayed at one time. They are currently wrapped inside stackpanels. The issue is both center vertically even though I set the vertical alignment on the text to be Top or Stretch. Hope that makes better sense.

Comment: If that's the case and they're separated anyway, @HighCore is right with his first comment. I could include an example but the points would be his.

Answer (score 0):

Does your booleanToVisibilityConverter return Visibility.Collapsed or .Hidden for False? It should return Collapsed in order for the space to be reclaimed.

Comment: [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) returns Visibility.Collapsed.

Comment: The built-in one does, yes but that was not in the initial WPF release. He doesn't say whether he's using the .NET supplied converter or a hand-created converted.

Comment: he said it was the built-in version in a now-deleted comment